# Android Tabhost save state of tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost, fragment

I have an Android app whose main activity is a tabhost.

How do I save the state of each tab? Right now, if I start at tab A, open a new Fragment C in the tab, go to tab B, then go back to tab A, I only see the original Tab A.

Tab A --> Fragment C

Tab B

How do I make it so I can see the backstack tab?

In general, if I modify the state of a tab, I want to be able to navigate away from it, come back, and see the modified state.

I'm currently detaching and attaching fragments when I switch tabs. Is this the wrong way to go about it? Is the issue something else?

Thanks!